# Jquery ajax function not returning success or failure suddenly

Tags: jquery, ajax

The function below has stopped working and I'm unable to track down the cause. It's not generating a success or failure message and nothing appears on the console.

Everything before the ajax portion of the function works fine. In PHP I put an echo on the controller and nothing is returned. Similar functions with near identical ajax calls are working fine in the same page.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('#template_id').change(function() {       

var src = "http://localhost/"+"templates/"+$('#template_id').val()+"/thumb.png";

    $('#template_image').attr("src", src);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost/index.php/resume/change_template',
        data: {
            resume_id : '297',                              
            template_id: $('#template_id').val()
        },
        success : function(msg){
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: did you check adding console.log(msg); inside success function...?

Comment: everything seems fine you need to check whether any js error is shown or not

Answer (score 1):

I think you dont miss anything there,try to use a firebug to see what is happening to ajax request

By the way you should also check if your ajax is being called

Answer (score 0):

It seems you put your `success` and `error` callbacks in `data` property, put them out:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'http://localhost/index.php/resume/change_template',
    data: {
        resume_id : '297',                              
        template_id: $('#template_id').val()
    },
    success : function(msg) {
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('failure');
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry -- these look identical to me except for the spaces. It looks like in both data is close by a '}' and then after the comma success start? What am I missing?

Comment: My fault :(, so is it possible that you use Fiddler to capture request/response roundtrip to see if there are any problems?